# "Being used in a disease" vs "being used on a disease"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, prepositions

> The treatment didn’t work, because it was being used **in/on** a disease
>   that wasn’t a disease.

A native English speaker told me *on* was the correct choice.

But Google Books returns [0](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1280&bih=938&tbm=bks&q=%22%20used%20on%20a%20disease%22&oq=%22%20used%20on%20a%20disease%22&gs_l=serp.3...44815.45794.0.45929.4.4.0.0.0.0.93.331.4.4.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..4.0.0.khKTMPTCl-8) results for *used on a disease* and [6](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1280&bih=938&tbm=bks&q=%22%20used%20in%20a%20disease%22&oq=%22%20used%20in%20a%20disease%22&gs_l=serp.3...174422.174483.0.174650.2.2.0.0.0.0.92.92.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..2.0.0.9quC72zfWUU) for *used in a disease*. So I'm confused. What's the correct usage and why?

Comment: "On" would be understood, *"against"* would be more natural (in the specific case of your sentence), "for" would be better in other circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you say:  "treatment **for** a disease".

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=treatment%20in%20a%20disease%2Ctreatment%20on%20a%20disease%2Ctreatment%20for%20%20a%20disease&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctreatment%20in%20a%20disease%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctreatment%20for%20a%20disease%3B%2Cc0): *for a disease* vs *in/on a disease.*

- The treatment didn't work, because it was (being used) for a disease that was not a disease.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "on a disease", but I would rather prefer: "used to treat" or "used for" or "used to cure" .